# How to eliminate rows in a dataframe by selecting a specific range for each column? - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe that displays information on property rentals in Brazil. This is a sample of the dataset:

```
data = {
    'city': ['São Paulo', 'Rio', 'Recife'],
    'area(m2)': [90, 120, 60],
    'Rooms': [3, 2, 4],
    'Bathrooms': [2, 3, 3],
    'animal': ['accept', 'do not accept', 'accept'],
    'rent($)': [2000, 3000, 800]}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=['city', 'area(m2)', 'Rooms', 'Bathrooms', 'animal', 'rent($)'])

print(df)
```

This is how the sample looks:

```
        city  area(m2)  Rooms  Bathrooms         animal  rent($)
0  São Paulo        90      3          2         accept     2000
1        Rio       120      2          3  do not accept     3000
2     Recife        60      4          3         accept      800
```

I want to filter the dataset in order to select only the apartments that have at maximum 2 rooms and 2 bathrooms.

Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
out=test_gdata.query('Bathrooms<=2 and Rooms<=2')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Nevertheless, I said at maximum 2 bathrooms and 2 rooms.  So, I think it would be the following: 'test_gdata.query('bathroom<=2and rooms<=2)'. Please, could you correct it in you code?

Comment: Updated answer **:)**

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
out = df.loc[(df.Rooms>=2) & (df.Bathrooms>=2)]
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! However, I said at maximum 2 bathrooms and 2 rooms. So, I think it would be the following: test_gdata.loc[(test_gdata.rooms<=2) & (test_gdata.bathroom<=2)]. Please, could you correct it in you code? Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the values on the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {
    'city': ['São Paulo', 'Rio', 'Recife'],
    'area(m2)': [90, 120, 60],
    'Rooms': [3, 2, 4],
    'Bathrooms': [2, 3, 3],
    'animal': ['accept', 'do not accept', 'accept'],
    'rent($)': [2000, 3000, 800]}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=['city', 'area(m2)', 'Rooms', 'Bathrooms', 'animal', 'rent($)'])

df_filtered = df[(df['Rooms'] <= 2) & (df['Bathrooms'] <= 2)]

print(df_filtered)
```

Returns

```
        city  area(m2)  Rooms  Bathrooms         animal  rent($)
0  São Paulo        90      3          2         accept     2000
1        Rio       120      2          3  do not accept     3000
2     Recife        60      4          3         accept      800
```